# Is this the correct way to commit a file only to cvs?

Tags: cvs

A file is changed and needs to be committed to cvs that file only, is this the correct way:-

```
    cvs commit -m "createTables.sql"
```

Comment: cant find exactly what I need on Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

```
cvs commit filename
```

Is what you need.

```
cvs commit -m "some text"
```

uses "some text" as the commit message.

Perhaps you want something like:

```
cvs commit -m "Commit file foo.bar" foo.bar
```

For future reference, the manual can be found here: http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#Committing